# Minimization algorithm to solve a 3 equations, 2 unknowns system

Tags: algorithm, optimization, minimization

As a civil engineer, I am working on a program to find the equilibrium of a concrete reinforced section submitted to a Flexural Moment.

Reinforced Concrete Cross Section Equilibrium:
[image: Reinforced Concrete Cross Section Equilibrium]

Basically, I have 2 unknowns, which are **eps_sup** and **eps_inf**

I have a constant that is **M**

I have some variables that depend only on the values of (**eps_sup**,**eps_inf**). The functions are non-linear, no need to go into this.

When I have the right couple of values, the following equations are verified :

Fc + Fs = 0 (Forces Equilibrium)

 M/z = Fc = -Fs (Moment Equilibrium)

My algorithm, as it is today, consists in finding the minimal value of : **abs(Fc+Fs)/Fc + abs(M_calc-M)/M**

To do this I iterate on Both **e eps_sup** and **eps_inf** between given limits, with a given step, and the step needs to be small enough to find a solution.

It is working, but it is very (very) slow since it goes through a very wide range of values without trying to reduce the number of iterations.

Surely I can find an optimized solution, and that is were I need your help.

```
'Constants :
M

'Variables :
delta = 10000000000000
eps_sup = 0
eps_inf = 0
M_calc = 0
Fc = 0
Fs = 0
z = 0
eps_sup_candidate = 0
eps_inf_candidate = 0


For eps_sup = 0 to 0,005 step = 0,000001
     For eps_inf = -0,05 to 0 step = 0,000001
             Fc = f(eps_sup,eps_inf)
             Fs = g(eps_sup,eps_inf)
             z = h(eps_sup,eps_inf)
             M_calc = Fc * z

             If (abs(Fc+Fs)/Fc + abs(M_calc-M)/M) < delta Then
                     delta = abs(Fc+Fs)/Fc + abs(M_calc-M)/M
                     eps_sup_candidate = eps_sup
                     eps_inf_candidate = eps_inf
             End If
     Next
Next
```

Comment: are f(), g(), and h() monotonic in both parameters?

Comment: I would suggest hill climbing.  If you can have local maxima, then hill climbing from a selection of points in a grid.  If you can only have one maximum, then hill climbing from anywhere.